# add model attribute in ajax POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I do an ajax POST call with json data, and I want to set a model attribute in the method POST, but it doesn't work.

My request in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="reubicar/idhu", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
public @ResponseBody Ubicacion detalleReubicarPorIdhu(@RequestBody Ubicacion jsonString, Model model) {
    List<Ubicacion> ubiLibres = userService.getUbicacionesLibres(jsonString.getReferencia(),"SUGERENCIA");
    model.addAttribute("ubilibres", ubiLibres);
    model.addAttribute("prueba", "esto es una prueba");
    return userService.getDetalleReubicar(jsonString);
}
```

In this request, I want to add the attributes ubilibres and prueba to the Model.

the jquery function:

```
var doButtonPress = function( idhuSel, ubicacionSel, referenciaSel ) {
            var datos = {
                    idhu: idhuSel,
                    ubicacion: ubicacionSel,
                    referencia: referenciaSel,
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/reubicar/idhu/',
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                //datatype: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(datos),
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(${prueba});
                },
                error: function(dataError) {

                }
            });                             
        }
```

When I use it in the success function, alert(${prueba}), it shows the value UNDEFINED. The same goes when I use it in the JSP:

```
<label for="inputComReubicar">${prueba}:</label>
```

where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the solution, but I have changed the ResponseBody and have added the values to the model returned.